# join multiple tables in linq query

Tags: linq, join, left-join

I have four related tables

```
1. Sales - {Sales_Id, Invoice_No, Invoice_Amount}
2. Sales_Details {Sale_Detail_Id, Sales_Id, Employee_Id,Commission}
3. Employee {Employee_Id, Employee_Name, Region_Id}
4. Region {Region_Id, Region_Name}
```

There are scenarios when one sale made by two employees together. I need a query to get
Sum(Invoice_Amount) and Region_Name by Region_Name

When I try to run below query, I am getting double records if sale made by two employees. How to resolve this?

```
from sale in cntx.Sales
join dtls in cntx.Sales_Details on sale.Sales_Id equals dtls.Sales_Id
join emp in cntx.Employee on dtls.Employee_Id equals emp.Employee_Id
join region in cntx.Region on emp.Region_Id equals region.Region_Id
group new
{
 region.Region_Name,
 sale.Invoice_Amount,
} by new { region.Region_Name } into g
orderby (g.Key.Region_Name)
select new
{
 regionName = g.Key.Region_Name,
 sumofInvoice = g.Sum(x => x.Invoice_Amount),
 counter = g.Count()
};
```

Comment: Well, how do you want it to look? What if a sale was made by two employees from different regions? Which region would the invoice be counted against?

Comment: The employees from same region only are allowed to do the sales together.

Comment: Hi. Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. Please act on [mcve]. In particular, find the smallest code that correctly does part of what you want that you can't extend to more of what you want. Plus execuable code with input. Explain what "getting double records" meands. Etc.